# Progressbar android with text inside

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a circular `ProgressBar`, I want inside this circular bar, write the progression in percentage (like 60 %, or 70 %..)
How can I do this inside the circular `ProgressBar`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBars"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            android:max="100" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check this tutorial on Progress Bars https://www.freakyjolly.com/show-progress-bar-with-text-and-title-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it overriding `onDraw` inside `ProgressBar`, and use `Canvas.drawText` to decide where the text should be positioned . [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) you can find the documentation for drwawText:

> x and y are the coordinates of the origin of the text being drawn

Comment: That's not true, look at @fllo's answer.

Comment: @yams I reworded my answer. OP didn't mention anywhere that he wanted to use an additional `TextView`, so my answer is not incorrect

Answer (score 10):

You should try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextProgress"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myProgress" android:layout_alignTop="@id/myProgress"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/myProgress" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myProgress"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

You also can with the `centerInParent` set to true, see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_hUy4w2hDJk).
And see [this tutorial](http://suyu-android-dev.blogspot.fr/2012/09/display-percentage-on-progressbar.html) or [this one](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-progress-bar-example.html#.Uw8Onfl5OGE) for more info to display your percentage.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `onDraw` way presents its own set of challenges between Android versions and devices. I have particularly liked using a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. If need be, use styles across various dpi's for consistency in UX.